# Testing injectivity/projectivity of specific objects in an abelian category

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories, valuation-theory

I have a valuation ring $A$, a full abelian subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $\text{Mod}_A$ and an object $M$ in $\mathcal{C}$. I know that $M$ is not a projective $A$-module, but that it can still be a projective object in a full subcategory nonetheless.

Given that $\mathcal{C}$ is not the category of **all** modules over a ring, I can't see anything that can be used to check injectivity or projectivity aside from the explicit definition in terms of monomorphisms and epimorphisms. For example, Baer's Criterion applies to checking injectivity in $\text{Mod}_A$, but not $\mathcal{C}$.

The precise details of the case I am looking at are as follows:

> Let $K$ be the field of Hahn series in an indeterminate $t$, with exponents in $\mathbb{R}$, coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and where we denote the valuation by $\nu$. Define $$A:=\{a\in K:\nu(a)\geq 0\},$$ $I_q:=t^qA$ and $I_{>q}:=\bigcup_{r>q}I_r$.
>
> Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be the strictly full additive subcategory generated by $A/I_q$, $A/I_{>q}$, $I_{>0}/I_q$, $I_{>0}/I_{>q}$, where $0<q\leq 1$ (but we also include $A/I_{>0}$). I am trying to determine whether or not $I_{>0}/I_{>1}$ is projective and/or injective in $\mathcal{C}$.

Any input much appreciated!

Comment: What's your definition of Abelian subcategory? Does it include that exact sequences of the subcategory remain exact in the supercategory? (This is Weibel's definition, for example)

Comment: @BadamBaplan In this case, I mean that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under finite direct sums of objects, and contains the kernels and cokernels (and hence images, coimages) of all morphisms between objects in $\mathcal{C}$. Unless I am mistaken, $\mathcal{C}$ is then itself abelian.

Comment: Got it, I hadn't actually read the part about the details of your case when I asked that.  I was wondering if you might actually be working with a full Grothendieck subcategory of $Mod(A)$, in which case the subcategory *would* be the category of all modules over a ring.

Comment: @BadamBaplan I didn't mention this, but $\mathcal{C}$ is identical to a full subcategory of $\text{Mod}_{A/I_{>1}}$. Things work a bit cleaner in the context of $A$-modules though.

Comment: @BadamBaplan I know that $\mathcal{C}$ is not closed under arbitrary direct sums (coproducts), so I don't think it is a Grothendieck category.

Comment: In the specific case you're interested in, I don't see any reason to expect that there is a better option than just testing the definition directly.